# Making a partial comparison of strings, one within a list, with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Fairly new to the world of Flutter and I've been searching for a built-in method that makes a partial match to one string value and an entire set of strings within a list.  For example...

Let's say I am querying the string "Farmhouse Sides, Coleslaw".

```
determineFood(String category) {


List<String> categoryArray = <String>[];

var breakFastWords = ["waffle", "toast", "pancake", "omelette", "Omelet"];
var lunchWords = ["salad", "sandwich", "soup", "burger", "pasta", "gyro", "hoagie"];
var dinnerWords = ["burger", "steak", "pork", "ribs"];
var sideWords = ["dressing", "drink", "mustard", "jelly", "peanuts", "coleslaw"];

test(String value) => value.contains(category);


if (breakFastWords.any(test))
{
  categoryArray.add("Breakfast");
}
```

Even using the function with test(String value) as opposed to a straight comparison of the string with the list with "contains", I am unable to get a match unless the two strings match EXACTLY (i.e. just "coleslaw" and "coleslaw).

Would anyone be able to suggest a better way to go about this?

Comment: You can convert the two string to all lowerCase first then after match the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One is very close to what you've done; however you need to call `.toLowerCase()` before matching the string. The other would be to use regex where you can tell it to ignore case.

Here's an example:

```
final breakfastWords = ["waffle", "toast", "pancake", "omelette", "Omelet"];
final lunchWords = ["salad", "sandwich", "soup", "burger", "pasta", "gyro", "hoagie"];
final dinnerWords = ["burger", "steak", "pork", "ribs"];
final sideWords = ["dressing", "drink", "mustard", "jelly", "peanuts", "coleslaw"];
final sideReg =  RegExp("(?:dressing|drink|mustard|jelly|peanuts|coleslaw)", caseSensitive: false);

bool isBreakfast(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return breakfastWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isLunch(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return lunchWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isDinner(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return dinnerWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isSide(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return sideWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isSideRegex(String string) {
  return sideReg.hasMatch(string);
}

void main() {
  String testString = "Farmhouse Sides, Coleslaw";
  
  if(isBreakfast(testString)) {
    print("It's breakfast");
  }
  
  if(isLunch(testString)) {
    print("It's lunch");
  }
  
  if(isDinner(testString)) {
    print("It's dinner");
  }
  
  if(isSide(testString)) {
    print("It's a side");
  }
  
  if(isSideRegex(testString)) {
    print("It's a side found with regex");
  }
}final breakfastWords = ["waffle", "toast", "pancake", "omelette", "Omelet"];
final lunchWords = ["salad", "sandwich", "soup", "burger", "pasta", "gyro", "hoagie"];
final dinnerWords = ["burger", "steak", "pork", "ribs"];
final sideWords = ["dressing", "drink", "mustard", "jelly", "peanuts", "coleslaw"];
final sideReg =  RegExp("(?:dressing|drink|mustard|jelly|peanuts|coleslaw)", caseSensitive: false);

bool isBreakfast(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return breakfastWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isLunch(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return lunchWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isDinner(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return dinnerWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isSide(String string) {
  String toTest = string.toLowerCase();
  return sideWords.any((word) => toTest.contains(word));
}

bool isSideRegex(String string) {
  return sideReg.hasMatch(string);
}

void main() {
  String testString = "Farmhouse Sides, Coleslaw";
  
  if(isBreakfast(testString)) {
    print("It's breakfast");
  }
  
  if(isLunch(testString)) {
    print("It's lunch");
  }
  
  if(isDinner(testString)) {
    print("It's dinner");
  }
  
  if(isSide(testString)) {
    print("It's a side");
  }
  
  if(isSideRegex(testString)) {
    print("It's a side found with regex");
  }
}
```

Also note that you could form your regex directly from the strings:

`final sideReg = RegExp("(?:${sideWords.join("|")})", caseSensitive: false);`